# Renamed dylib, sudo stopped working

Tags: macos, sudo

I renamed the dylib

```
/usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
```

for testing purposes, but when I tried to change it back I had to realize that

```
sudo mv ...
```

cannot be run because it needs exactly this dylib.

How can I fix this?

You may laugh now.

Comment: Can you rename the file to it's proer name though Finder?

Comment: Permission denied. How can I rename a file which needs root privileges in Finder?

Comment: In my previous Mac OS X experience, doing stuff in Finder let me get around similar permissions issues. Can you run "su -" and get a root shell?

Comment: su: pam_start: system error ... So no, not working.

Comment: Grab your install/rescue media.

Comment: MacBook Pro 15 Retina, no such thing... Or is there?

Comment: There is, you just may have to look harder for it.

Comment: What are you saying?

Comment: Haha, this is hilarious. I did the exact same thing (rename libz.1.dylib for testing purposes) but I went a step further and restarted my Mac. Big mistake. Just wouldn't start up. Booted into verbose mode and turned out that CoreFoundation was looking for this file and couldn't find it so the boot always failed.

Answer (score 2):

1. Reboot the Mac (you may have to press and hold "Power" button if it halts).
2. When or before Apple logo appears, press "Cmd+R" a lot of times.
3. Wait until Recovery mode window appears.
4. Open "Terminal" from the top menu.
5. `cd` to `/Volumes/Macintosh HD/usr/lib`
6. Rename the library back: you are already the root user.
7. Reboot the Mac.

I've encountered the same problem an hour ago: replaced `libsqlite3.dylib` with a broken one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the end I booted Linux and renamed it back. So, I cannot check, if your solution works, but it sounds good :-)

Comment: This solution did indeed work for me. See my comment to the original post.